# Implementing a progress bar in WinForms app during parsing XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, progress-bar

I made an application that passes trough an XML file and "extracts" the entries that have a specific value of a certain attribute. The application works fine, but the XML file has over 52,000 entries and only 3 values to sort by (so naturally it takes some time to execute it). Because of that I want to implement a progress bar so I can follow the progress my application made. I googled it, but none of the solutions work for me (the application does it's work, but the progress bar doesn't move at all), so if you could help me that would be grate.

The code that extracts the entries is this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes;
string ExtractedXML = "";

private void extractingXMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (nodes.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (String.Compare(node.ChildNodes[6].ChildNodes[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value.ToString(), "CodeValue") == 0)
            {
                tempXML = node.InnerXml;
                temp = "<" + node.Name + " code=\"" + node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value + "\">" + Environment.NewLine;
                temp += tempXML + Environment.NewLine;
                temp += "</" + node.Name + ">";
                ExtractedXML += temp + Environment.NewLine;
                temp = ""; 
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = ExtractedXML;
    }
}
```

There is a ToolStripMenue item for each value with similar code, only the "CodeValue" changes. How can I implement the progress bar to show me how far did the application get?

Comment: Use an XML library or at least a StringBuilder. You may see so much improvement that you don't need a ProgressBar anymore.

Comment: I omitted the progress bar because it didn't do anything, and the delegate functions were just throwing me errors. My question is how to implement progress bar to track the progress of this function.
As for using XML library, I never worked with them and when I try to google it, I get results for XmlTextReades and similar functions. I've seen some xpath examples and tried to implement them, but unsuccessfully. Any suggestion is very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do your long running process inside of a separate thread, [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) would be useful here. When kicking off your process call:

```
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(//pass in object to process)
```

Then have a `ReportProgress` event where you increment your progress bar e.g.

```
private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

And finally, inside of the `do work` event you'll want to call report progress with your formula for getting the percentage completed, as well as passing in a processed result, here's an example i've used:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        bgWorker.ReportProgress((outputGrid.Rows.Count * 100) / importGrid.Rows.Count, result);   
}
```

Comment: And always check for `e.Error` in the completed event.

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to do, is to not process the XML on the UI thread.

The reason why you don't see the progressbar increasing, is because processing that XML probably uses all resources and the UI thread has no chance of updating it's controls, until processing the XML has finished.

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the processing, and use the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event to let the UI know that it should update the progressbar.
By doing so, your application will remain responsive, and the UI will not freeze.  The UI thread will be handed some CPU time as well, and it is able to update his controls and respond to events.